# Difficult understanding while comparing tuples in swift

Tags: swift, tuples

```
   Program 1:
   (1, "zebra") < (2, "apple")   // true because 1 is less than 2, "zebra" and "apple" are not compared

   Program 2:
  (3, "apple") < (3, "bird")    // true because 3 is equal to 3, "apple" is less than "bird"

   Program 3:
  (4, "dog") == (4, "dog")      // true because 4 is equal to 4, "dog" is equal to "dog"
```

what is the use of these operaters in between the tuples

How come apple is less than birds?

Comment: What result did you expect in the second case, and why?

Comment: i expected  false because there is not less than three and apple and bird can bird cannot be compared So (false,false) is false

Comment: yeah martin@MartinR

Comment: Tuples are compared “lexicographically” – see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1541163 and https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0015-tuple-comparison-operators.md.

Answer (score 2):

Tuples are compared an element at a time until all elements have been compared or you reach an answer.

```
(1, 9) < (2, 3)  // true
```

This is true because `1 < 2`.  There is no need to go further, because checking from left to right, as soon as you find that `<` is `true` for one element, it is `true` for the whole tuple.  This works exactly like integers where both integers have the same number of digits; `19 < 23` because of the ten's digit.  There is no need to look at the one's digit.

---

Strings are compared in alphabetical order.  `"apple" < "zebra"` because it comes first alphabetically (just as if you were putting a list of words in alphabetical order).

---

```
(1, "zebra") < (2, "apple") // true
```

This is true because `1 < 2`.  We stopped before even considering `"zebra"` and `"apple"` because *they don't matter here, the comparison already satisfies `<`*.

---

```
(3, "apple") < (3, "bird")  // true
```

In this case, we compare `3` and `3`, but they're equal.  At this point, we don't have enough information to decide if the first tuple is `<` the second tuple, so we move on to the next item.  Since `"apple" < "bird"`, we conclude that the whole first tuple is less than the second.  This is just like comparing `30` and `31`.  You look at the ten's digit and see that they are the same, so you move on to comparing the one's digit.

---

```
(4, "dog") == (4, "dog")  // true
```

When comparing two tuples for equality, you compare elements from left to right.  You can quit as soon as you find a mismatch and conclude that the answer is `false`.  To decide that the answer is `true`, you have to compare all corresponding elements and find that they all match.

Comment: Did that help, @subhashchandru?  Comments?

Answer (score 1):

> How come apple is less than birds?

Because A for apple comes before B for bird in the Roman alphabet. Alphabetical order is ABCDE...

Comment: so why zebra and apple cannot be compared @matt

Comment: They can be compared.